JSON_CONTAINS check exact json not inside it codeigniter php
Here is my query:
 $this->db->select('*')->from('users')->where(['doctor_id' => NULL])->where("JSON_CONTAINS(chamber_id, '2', '$')")->get()->result()

chamber_id store in database is ["2","47","93"]
I want data where array of chamber id have "2" inside. if its happened with raw query

If you're searching for a value in a JSON array, use MEMBER OF. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of

You need to update the where clause since you're saving the IDs with (") double quotes (["2","47","93"]), to the code below:
where("JSON_CONTAINS(chamber_id, '\"2\"', '$') ")

Also, check the full documentation MySQL Doc
